# How to work around Restriction on Distinct in for update clause

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c

```
 select distinct t._id from terra.wl_log t
        where t.in_queue = 'Y'  
        for update skip locked "
```

**Restrictions on the FOR UPDATE Clause**

> You cannot specify this clause with the following other constructs:
>   the DISTINCT operator, CURSOR expression, set operators,
>   group_by_clause, or aggregate functions.

I need to select distinct **_id** for update. Thiw statement executes several times.
How to work around this restriction?

Comment: Tell us a bit more about the problem - what are you going to do next with this data?

Comment: You need to decide which row you need to update.  Oracle refuses  DISTINCT in the context because  DISTINCT generally 'erases' any row reference and the result set is not updatable anymore.

Comment: The alternate solution for this can be creating a Global temporary table and inserting the record to that table and using it,

Comment: @XING How does this help lock the records?

Comment: use this `select t._id from terra.wl_log t where t.in_queue = 'Y' group by t._id`

Comment: How do you want to update these row in next step? Are you going to use something like this `update table where id = distinct_id` ?

Comment: @TonyAndrews I only prososed an alternate solution which has nothing to do with locking the rows. What i wanted to communicate that inplace of using `For Update` for a particular run, select records for that particular run and put it in a GTT and use it. Next run again follow the same.